# Type parsing in SWIFT

Tags: ios, parsing, swift, type-conversion

Having a string value, how can one check if it's a Valid Date, a valid Decimal, a valid Bool, etc.

For int I know there is **.toInt()** which returns an optional. What about the others?

Basically I'm trying a to do a **.tryParse(string: String)** scenario

Comment: I think there is no method available for doing this.
but for some other way that helps you like

for date used NSDateFormatter

var formatter: NSDateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
formatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd-HH-mm-ss"
let dateTimePrefix: Date! = formatter.DatefromString(NSDate())

for Double value

var string_2 : NSString = "100"
var number_2 : Double! = string_2.doubleValue

Comment: What about `NSDateFormatter` for dates?

Comment: You gotta write the code, with the details depending on the level of precision you need.  (Though NSDateFormatter is pretty darn good for dates.)

Answer (score 0):

For decimals:

```
(string as NSString).floatValue // 0.0 if not successful
(string as NSString).doubleValue // 0.0 if not successful
```

There is also

```
(string as NSString).boolValue
```

but it's not very useful, as it returns `'true'` for any non-zero number (in accordance with Objective-C `BOOL`). We can write our own Swift `Bool`  parser:

```
extension String {
    func toBool() -> Bool? {
        switch self {
        case "true":
            return true
        case "false":
            return false
        default:
            return nil
        }
    }
}

let boolValue = string.toBool()
```

It works, but it returns an `Optional<Bool>`, which can be confusing.

Dates are not so easy to parse in general, so we can't just have some `toDate()` method. We need (at least) something like

```
let formater = NSDateFormatter()
formater.dateFormat = "DD-MM-YYYY" // for example
formater.locale = // set some locale
let date = formater.dateFromString("21-12-2014")
```